AWS Lambda stops handling SQS queue triggers
Update: I figured out that aws thinks am in a recursive loop. There is a metric called "Recursive invocations dropped" and when it reaches 16 it quits. Once I figure out how to handle this Ill post my answer.
I have an SQS queue and a lambda as event source mapping for that queue. The lambda's job is to parse some data from an S3 file in batches of 100. There are 10000+ entries in this file.
What I do is:

Process the 100 rows
Create a new queue job to process the next 100 by sending start/end parameters.

The process works great for 1600 entries and fails everytime exactly there. My last log entry which logs the sending as well as the metadata from SQS send command as well as the successful end of the lambda is this:
2024/06/30/[$LATEST]82e77466cf99479ca05c453e6da39436 2024-06-30T00:25:39.579000 {
  "timestamp": "2024-06-30T00:25:39.579Z",
  "level": "INFO",
  "requestId": "2035819e-7b43-5e5f-9d0a-df64dcbed81a",
  "message": {
    "message": "Processing batch 1601-1700 of contacts-full16.csv",
    "data": {
      "$metadata": {
        "httpStatusCode": 200,
        "requestId": "9b5e2cfe-21cd-5649-9ade-7204898e4803",
        "attempts": 1,
        "totalRetryDelay": 0
      },
      "MD5OfMessageAttributes": "793a908cbea235c2c3fbfed4b9ee333a",
      "MD5OfMessageBody": "c98b6d9c345a46fccf6d6cc6d92e99e9",
      "MessageId": "99a6d3bc-d0b3-41cd-882f-28ffc3064dd0"
    }
  }
}
2024/06/30/[$LATEST]82e77466cf99479ca05c453e6da39436 2024-06-30T00:25:39.581000 {
  "time": "2024-06-30T00:25:39.581Z",
  "type": "platform.report",
  "record": {
    "requestId": "2035819e-7b43-5e5f-9d0a-df64dcbed81a",
    "metrics": {
      "durationMs": 50593.656,
      "billedDurationMs": 50594,
      "memorySizeMB": 512,
      "maxMemoryUsedMB": 145
    },
    "tracing": {
      "spanId": "15844fe56191b17e",
      "type": "X-Amzn-Trace-Id",
      "value": "Root=1-6680a5d0-5d097410faf01195360c7e44;Parent=5c5e05fe243ddd01;Sampled=1"
    },
    "status": "success"
  }
}


The lambda exited with "success" just like it did 15-16 times before.  Looking at my queue it says 1 message in flight, nothing in DLQ.
Here's my CF (SAM):
Resources:
  DeadLetterQueue:
    Type: AWS::SQS::Queue
    UpdateReplacePolicy: Delete
    DeletionPolicy: Delete

  SQSQueue:
    Type: AWS::SQS::Queue
    UpdateReplacePolicy: Delete
    DeletionPolicy: Delete
    Properties:
      QueueName: my-queue
      MessageRetentionPeriod: 86400
      VisibilityTimeout: 1800
      RedrivePolicy:
        deadLetterTargetArn: !GetAtt DeadLetterQueue.Arn
        maxReceiveCount: 3
  
  SQSQueueHandler:
    Type: AWS::Serverless::Function
    Properties:
      CodeUri: src/handlers/
      Handler: sync.lambdaHandler
      Runtime: nodejs20.x
      MemorySize: 512
      Timeout: 300
      Policies:
        - AmazonSQSFullAccess
     
  LambdaFunctionEventSourceMapping:
    Type: AWS::Lambda::EventSourceMapping
    Properties:
      BatchSize: 10
      Enabled: true
      EventSourceArn: !GetAtt SQSQueue.Arn
      FunctionName: !GetAtt SQSQueueHandler.Arn

I have tried this 4 times and it always stops at that same exact point - I am wondering if there is some cap/limit of how many times this will work - perhaps it is waiting now but not sure.  I don't see any info on my console nor through searching that indicates there would be a parameter that would limit this.
I have tried playing with batch size as well as the lambda source concurrency but nothing changes.
Any ideas?  I've even placed dummy code for the row processing to no avail - it seems to work great except for the fact that the 16th SQS request never gets picked up by the lambda.

What do you mean by "Create a new queue job"? Are you saying that you initially send one message to the queue to process the first 100 rows and then that Lambda sends a message to the queue that should trigger the Lambda function again to process the 2nd 100 rows? Presumably this is to avoid the 15 minute limit on the Lambda function? Have you considered running the code somewhere else (eg EC2 instance, AWS Batch, Fargate) instead of using Lambda? Have you tried starting by sending the "1600" message to the queue and see whether it fails immediately, or whether it fails at 3200?

@JohnRotenstein I just figured it out by looking at function dashboard. Evidently aws thinks am in a recursive loop and 16 is the count they use.  As to why a queue - its a one time large import then will be smaller ones once a week so lambda triggered my s3 makes sense - I wanted to ensure I could do bigger for those rare cases hence the queue.

A 'normal' method would be to have S3 trigger a Lambda function that then puts ALL messages into the queue. You would then have another Lambda function that processes the messages from the queue. This allows the messages to be processed in parallel. If you don't want parallel processing, you can set a Reserved Concurrency of 1 on the queue. If you need the messages to be processed strictly in-order, then use a FIFO queue.

@JohnRotenstein agreed - that is going to be my approach though I am challenged by the fact that once the file gets all processed I then need to process a few related files that have to come after. So perhaps another queue/handler whose sole job is to receive task making tasks. What do you think?  so S3 calls queue1 with filename only and handler makes mini tasks for queue2. When done queue2 handler adds files to queue1 for same. I could invoke but I fear AWS will think this part of same logic and call it a recursive issue.

It will not be recursive if you are simply sending messages to a queue. It is only recursive if the Lambda function is invoking itself directly. The hard part is recognising when all of the main file is processed. You could have Lambda #1 send all messages and then add an "all finished" message to the queue. However, you would need to ensure that message is processed last by using a FIFO queue and by setting the MessageGroupID to the same value for all messages. This ensures that the messages will be processed in sequence. Or, you could use AWS Step Functions but that is more complex.

Ah good point I didn't even think about the fact it would happen all at once. Yes FIFO would be the approach. Thank you
